# Strange language on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android studio is rendering some strange character, can't seem to understand why. It was absolutely fine a couple of days back, and I don't remember making any changes.

Tried restarting a couple of times, didn't help.

[image: Studio]

Can somebody tell how to get back to original form?
P.S I am running Windows 10

Comment: Specify the OS you're running

Comment: @m0skit0 Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to a problem with your font. You can change it from here:

> File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugVwW.png)

Answer (score 0):

To reset your Android Studio settings, go

> Computer > Users > Your Username > .Androidstudio

and delete the .Androidstudio folder.